# Two strings are equal but python says they are not

Tags: python

I have the following code which helps to bruteforce hashes
The first if statement will run, the values are `hash=wordlist.txt`, `args=abtfg`, `values=[0, "0,1", 0, wordlist.txt, true]`

```
def bruteforce(hash, args, values):
    if "." in hash:
        files = open(values[args.find("f")]) # Open wordlist.txt
        for xhsd in files.readlines():
            hash = xhsd
            alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            alphabet += alphabet.upper() + "0123456789!$%^&*(){}~#][;:'@/?.>,<"
            if "b" in args: # It is
                m = args.find("b")
                m = values[m]
            else:
                m = "0,16"
            # m is 0,10
            start_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
            l = 0
            print("Cracking...")
            attempts = 0
            while l == 0:
                password = ""
                for x in range(random.randrange(int(m.split(",")[0])+1,int(m.split(",")[1])+1)): # range(random.randrange(0,10))
                    password += alphabet[random.randrange(0,len(alphabet)-1)]
                num = hash_types[int(values[args.find("t")])] # num="md5"
                htype = "hash2 = hashlib."+num+"(password).hexdigest()"
                exec(htype) # hash2 = md5(password)
                print hash2 + ":" + hash # Compares the hashes
                if hash == hash2:
                    print password
                    l = 1
                else:
                    print "Trying..."
```

The first item it tries, it cracks it almost instantly, printing:

```
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661:0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
```

(this is hash2 and hash). So we now know these two variables are equal. However, the if statement directly below it, doesn't run. This is the weirdest thing I've seen in Python, could anyone explain why this is? I've printed both variables and they're clearly the same...

Comment: Trailing newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing whitespace could help:

```
if hash.strip() == hash2.strip():
```